# How do I make a dynamic list of pages in a folder?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm still somewhat new to web development, so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question. I have a site that has several hundred pages that I want to be alphabetically sorted automatically when a user goes to another page. For example, I would want the list to be shown on `root/example/index.html` displaying all pages named "index.html" in `root/example/things/thingsubfolder` or `root/example/things/` , whichever is easiest to do. I'm not sure if this is a JS question or a PHP question or a SQL question or a XML question or something else, as I'm not all that familiar with any of those, except for JS.

I don't really care if this would have to use a table or an actual list or anything else, I just don't want to be stuck doing this by hand.

I haven't actually tried to run anything, as I don't really know where I should start after a few days of searching Google to no avail.

Comment: This is a job for searching the web for "PHP list directory content" and then applying that new knowledge to a script that generates some HTML output.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you, I'll try to see if this works later. It looks like exactly what I was trying to find but couldn't really describe in a search bar.